# Ignore AudioKit calls in Thread Sanitizer

Tags: swift, audiokit

Does anyone know how I'd suppress AudioKit calls with a `called_from_lib:` Thread Sanitizer suppression? I've tried `called_from_lib:AudioKit`, `called_from_lib:AudioKit.framework`, and `called_from_lib:AudioKit.swiftmodule`, to no avail.

Comment: I guess the parser uses regex, so I was able to (provisionally) ignore all AudioKit data race warnings with `race:AK*` in my Tsan.supp file. Will do the trick, for now (though I'd still be curious about the original question).